# Apache kafka : broker leader -1 (topic received from Orion via Cygnus)

Tags: apache-kafka, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm working with Apache Kafka and receiving topics from Orion Context Broker via Cygnus (Fiware Labs)

I'm receiving 10 topics, and I can see data arriving in the consumer console for 8 topics.

But for 2 others topics, I cannot see any data arriving. And there is no error code (the consumer is just empty). If i try to add a test line to the topic via the producer console, i get this error:

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic sensors_presence2_sensors with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: Batch Expired (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

So I used the describe command and I get this :

```
Topic:sensors_presence2_sensors PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: sensors_presence2_sensors    Partition: 0    Leader: -1  Replicas: 2 Isr:
```

I'm just starting with Kafka, so for the moment I have 1 broker(0) and no partition. But why is my leader -1 ? This broker do not even exist. How can I change that ? I didn't choose the configuration for my topic, they arrived automatically from Cygnus (Orion Context Broker) with a OrionKafkaSink.

An example of one of the 8 topics that works well :

```
Topic:sensors_presence1_sensors PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic:sensors_presence1_sensors Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Thanks

Edit : In Cygnus logs, it shows that data is correctly send to kafka :

```
time=2016-03-02T11:07:09.504UTC | lvl=INFO | trans=1456915468-194-0000000039 | srv=egmmqtt | subsrv=egmmqttpath | function=persistAggregation | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionKafkaSink[279] : [kafka-sink] Persisting data at OrionKafkaSink. Topic (sensors_presence2_sensors), Data (...
```

Comment: Leader -1 means that something is wrong. It should be 0 or up.

Comment: Can you try `./kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh --zookeeper={YOURZK}`? That will try to reassign partitions over available brokers. (1 in your case)

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that and it didn't reassigned partition for my topic...it is still  leader -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of describe command is showing Replicas:2 and Isr: (empty) that means broker with id 2 was active at the time of creation of that topic and the same broker(id=2) is not active now. Because of that Isr( In sync replicas) showing empty.

There is no chance of getting Replicas: 2 when you have only one node (broker-id=0) kafka cluster. Make broker-2 up and everything will works well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You might be onto something, but `ReplicationFactor:1` in both cases, so it should not try to use multiple brokers. However that `Replicas: 2` and `Replicas: 0` is weird.